# Positive or negatively bounded CDFs

Tags: continuous-data, cumulative-distribution-function, integral, bounds, numerical-integration

If $X\in\mathbb{R}^n$ is a continuous random variable whose cumulative distribution function is ordinarily

$$F_X(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_X(x) dx $$

what is the meaning of

$$F_X(x) = \int_{0}^{\infty} f_X(x) dx $$

and

$$F_X(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{0} f_X(x) dx $$

given that probabilities only have a support of $[0,1]$? How would each be affected by the exclusion of its complementary half (the other)? Are there any methods that utilize these "bounded CDFs" and for what applications?

(Simplest answer can be in terms of a Gaussian CDF, which has a bell-shaped PDF)

Comment: This surely and sorely needs a context of where you encountered these definitions, which should be expected to answer the question.

Comment: the fact that something so general is not readily utilized in statistical models made me think that the exclusion of complementaries that  these two formulas impose presents either no added value for intuitive analysis compared to viewing the whole, or numerical issues maybe at their boundaries. but we very well deal with data everyday whose signage is of major importance, so i thought both would be popular for the segregation of the upside and downside in numerous applications, but it's not

Comment: Probabilities are contained in [0, 1], not supported on [0, 1] in general. "Support" means this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_(measure_theory)

Comment: The first formula is incorrect: the right hand side always equals $1.$  The other two formulas are nonsensical unless $n=1.$

Comment: $n=1$ as in the original data only contains 1 observation?

Comment: No; you (still) define your notation as working with $X\in\mathbb{R}^n$, so in an $n$-dimensional space. @whuber is pointing out that the restriction $n = 1$ is needed for the  equations to make sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The expressions you've written are not functions of $x$. When you find the definite integral with respect to $x$ of a function $f$ as $\int_a^b f(x) dx$, you get a constant corresponding to the signed area between the graph of $f(x)$ and the $x$-axis.

Your expressions are equal to the (constant) probability that $X$ is positive, and the (constant) probability that $X$ is negative
$$
P(X > 0) = \int_0^\infty f_X (x) dx \qquad P(X < 0) = \int_{-\infty}^0 f_X (x) dx ,
$$
[see here for details.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Absolutely_continuous_univariate_distributions)

Comment: Helpful (and more careful than my first reading of the question). Although what the OP wrote is what they wrote I have to wonder whether they meant $\int_0^x$ and $\int_{-\infty}^x$ which would be (more like) bounded distribution functions?

Comment: no, negative and positive domains of the original data were only meant

Comment: The title word _functions_ is then quite wrong.

Comment: I say title word: _functions_ is implicit in CDFs.